# Form submit doesn't update database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create lists and each has 2 attributes name and description.Database does create it and save it when using console but not using the website form.When checking the log file I found that website form does not post instead uses gets and is redirected to itself, How do I make the website form POST instead of GET so it gets stored in database.

Log file:

Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-18 12:35:14 -0400
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Here is list controller:

```
 def create
    @list = Lists.new(params[:lists])
    if @list.save
      redirect_to @list
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

   def update
    if @list.update_attributes(params[:lists])

      flash[:success] = "lists updated"
      redirect_to @list
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

def new
    @list = Lists.new
  end
```

---

This is the form for users to create list

```
<%= form_for @list, url: newlist_path(@list), html: { method: :put } do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </br>
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>


      <%= f.submit "Create the List" %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: are you sure your model name is Lists not List

Comment: by default the create is a POST not put. please check and confirm your create action is executing after submitting the form

Comment: it creates and saves using console, it doesn't create nor saves when using website to enter data so form on website isn't saving, so isnt there something wrong with form because create works when using console

Comment: Agree, I'd put a `raise params.to_yaml` in the first line of the `update` method in the controller to see if it is really hitting the `update` method.

Comment: i am talking about the create action not create method of active record. check after submitting the form which action is being called.

Comment: what rails do you use? if the 4th strong_parameters can clean params

Comment: add "!" to `save` method - and read what is wrong (exception) in log

Comment: I did put raise params.to_yaml but it didn't show any errors when I tried to make list using form,it just didn't do anything and reloaded the page

Comment: Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-18 12:35:14 -0400
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)             When checking log file I found that it doesn't post anything to database instead it just gets redirected to itself but in the create method I have it get redirect to @list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form_for` helper is routing to the incorrect action. Try routing to the `create` action instead:

```
<%= form_for @list, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your controller's code excerpt you've pasted is complete, but you might missed to initialize list object for update. In your `update` action you have only

```
if @list.update_attributes(params[:lists])
```

but you are not initializing `@list` variable before. So you probably need something like

```
@list = Lists.find(params[:id])
```

You can also inspect your log file and verify what parameters are sent to controller.

Comment: def show
  @list = Lists.find(params[:id])
 end
 
 def edit
 @list= Lists.find(param[:id])
 end

Comment: Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-18 12:35:14 -0400 Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms) When checking log file I found that it doesn't post anything to database instead it just gets redirected to itself but in the create method I have it get redirect to @list